# Remote Desktop from Windows to Debian on AWS?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, debian

I need to set up a Remote Desktop connection from Windows 8 to a Debian instance running on AWS. I've tried modifying the Ubuntu instructions [from AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-to-linux-desktop-from-windows/), replacing the ubuntu-desktop with task-desktop. When I connect sesman tells me

```
connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350
sesman connect ok
sending login info to session manager, please wait ...
xrdp_mm_process_login_response: login successful for display ..
started connecting
connecting to 127.0.0.1 5910
error - problem connecting
```

There's nothing helpful in /var/log/auth.log or /var/log/xrdp-sesman.log.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have X running on Debian?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the place to look was in ~/.xsession-errors, where it was complaining that it couldn't find xfce4-session.
After looking [at the Debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Xfce) it looks like the way to start xfce on Debian is to use startxfce4, not xfce4-session.

So the complete solution seems to be:

1. Start with the template provided by AWS [at the AWS website](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-to-linux-desktop-from-windows/)
2. Refer to the default user for Debian ('admin') instead of the default user for Ubuntu ('ubuntu')
3. Use some alternative desktop; I am using task-desktop instead of ubuntu-desktop here
4. Use startxfce4 instead of xfce4-session in .xsession

Answer (score 0):

you should guis with this steps

1. `sudo apt update && apt upgrade`

   2. `sudo sed -i 's/^PasswordAuthentication no/PasswordAuthentication yes/' /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
   3. `sudo /etc/init.d/ssh restart`
   4. `sudo passwd ubuntu`
   5. `sudo apt install xrdp xfce4 xfce4.goodies tightvncserver`
   6. `echo xfce4.session> /home/ubuntu/.xsession`
   7. `sudo cp /home/ubuntu/.xsession /etc/skel`
   8. sudo sed -i '0,/-1/s//ask-1'/etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`
   9. `changes coincdencias`
   10. `sudo sed -i '0,/-1/s//ask-1/' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`
   11. `sudo service xrdp restart`
   12. `sudo sed -i '0,/ask-1/s//-1/' /etc/xrdp/xrdp.ini`

[check example image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVMdj.png)
and
check my post facebook

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10218879958565053&set=a.1751108612582&type=3

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your sed commands? I'm not great at regex and do not know content of xrdp.ini, so I have no clue what those commands do